# Get echo message from php

Tags: php, android, json

I am doing httppost method in order to send 3 parameters to php. The 3 parameters are use in mysql query to retrieve particular record.
However, my json.getInt() is point to null. Is there any way I can get the echo message?

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread


                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item_ID", itemID));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("booking_StartDate", checkStartDate));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("booking_EndDate", checkEndDate));

                    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_checkAvaibility, "POST", params);
                    // Check for success tag

                    try {
                        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if(records == null){
                            success =0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            success =1;
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



            return null;
        }
```

---

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will get single product details
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
$item_ID = $_POST['item_ID'];
$bookingStartDate = $_POST['booking_StartDate'];
$bd2 = strtotime($bookingStartDate);
$bd3 = date('Y-m-d',$bd2);
$bookingEndDate = $_POST['booking_EndDate'];
$be2 = strtotime($bookingEndDate);
$be3 = date('Y-m-d',$be2);


    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT booking_ID,booking_Title FROM booking_record where booking_Status='Approved' and item_ID='$item_ID' and (booking_StartDate between '$bd3' and '$be3' or booking_EndDate between '$bd3' and '$be3')") or die(mysql_error());

    if (!empty($result)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        // check for empty result
            $record = array();
            $record ["booking_ID"] = $result["booking_ID"];
        $record ["booking_Title"] = $result["booking_Title"];
        $response["records"] = array();     

        array_push($response["records"], $record);
            $response["success"] = 1;


       echo json_encode($response);




        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }}else{
        $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Error";
}


?>
```

I get null pointer exception in this line.

```
int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
```

JSON makeHttpRequest method

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
           List<NameValuePair> params) {

       // Making HTTP request
       try {

           // check for request method
           if(method == "POST"){
               // request method is POST
               // defaultHttpClient
               DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
               httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

               HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
               HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
               is = httpEntity.getContent();

           }else if(method == "GET"){
               // request method is GET
               DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
               url += "?" + paramString;
               HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

               HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
               HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
               is = httpEntity.getContent();
           }           

       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       try {
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                   is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           String line = null;
           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line);
           }
           is.close();
           json = sb.toString();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
       }

       // try parse the string to a JSON object
     /*try {
           jObj = new JSONObject(json);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data "+json + e.toString());
       }*/

       // return JSON String
     try {
        return new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     return null;
   }
```

Logcat

```
> 03-12 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689): FATAL EXCEPTION:
> AsyncTask #1 03-12 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
> doInBackground() 03-12 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):     at
> android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278) 03-12 02:36:57.928:
> E/AndroidRuntime(12689):  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
> 03-12 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
> 03-12 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
> 03-12 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 03-12
> 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):    at
> android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208) 03-12
> 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
> 03-12 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
> 03-12 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):  at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 03-12 02:36:57.928:
> E/AndroidRuntime(12689): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 03-12 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):  at
> com.example.mysqltesting.ShowAvaibility$GetProductDetails.doInBackground(ShowAvaibility.java:89)
> 03-12 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):  at
> com.example.mysqltesting.ShowAvaibility$GetProductDetails.doInBackground(ShowAvaibility.java:1)
> 03-12 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):  at
> android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264) 03-12 02:36:57.928:
> E/AndroidRuntime(12689):  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
> 03-12 02:36:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(12689):  ... 5 more
```

This is the latest logcat I get

```
03-12 03:54:28.956: D/JSON-OUTPUT(22405): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head><body><h1>Forbidden</h1><p>You don't have permission to access /checkAva.phpon this server.</p><hr><address>Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at 192.168.1.132 Port 80</address></body></html>
03-12 03:54:28.961: E/JSON Parser(22405): Error parsing data <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head><body><h1>Forbidden</h1><p>You don't have permission to access /checkAva.phpon this server.</p><hr><address>Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at 192.168.1.132 Port 80</address></body></html>org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Does this code echo out in a browser? additionally can you provide this method jParser.makeHttpRequest(). Where is this json file located ? your localhost?

Comment: Ya it echo out in browser, this is the echo message.
{"records":[{"booking_ID":"15","booking_Title":"abc"}],"success":1}

Yup, in localhost.
I have upload the jparser.makeHttpRequest() @inner_class7

Comment: are you testing this in an emulator or on your phone?

Comment: post your logcat , it looks the jsonobject is null.

Comment: Im testing on my phone, but the application will stop because of the null pointer. I try to run the php at Advanced Rest Client, it works fine. @inner_class7

Comment: I have posted it. @SanjeetAjnabee

Comment: right after `json = sb.toString();` try calling `Log.d("JSON-OUTPUT" , json);` and see if this outputs your json.

Comment: is the Log.d("JSON-OUTPUT" , json); need to be placed in JParser class? @inner_class7

Comment: @SanjeetAjnabee I think my JSONObject is null, is that means Im failed to pass the data into the php?

Comment: No, The the jsonObject is not being initiated , Can log the json(String ) in the JSONParser class.? Or Simply log the exception form the last catch block? Since stacktrace is not showing the json parse errors.

Comment: I get the latest logcat from json praser, it says that i have no permission to access the php. @SanjeetAjnabee

Comment: I get the latest logcat from json praser, it says that i have no permission to access the php. @inner_class7

Comment: You canot access localhot of your pc form your mobile , you need to do some setup to access that from your mobile, if you want to do that then configure your server for that or test it form a live on.

Comment: Before this I have one function call add booking, it creates booking from mobile and save at the localhost, and it is works, but now all of the php files are not working, saying that i have no permission to access. @SanjeetAjnabee

Comment: Do some  set up so you could access it from "192.168.1.132 Port 80" :)
I cannot help you more now. going to bed.:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what You need to do after reviewing your error,

you need to edit etc/apache2/httpd.conf and make sure you have `require all granted` which will allow anyone on your network to access the folder you server from Note: I am on a mac.

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/USER_NAME_HERE/FOLDER_YOU_SERVE_FROM/"
<Directory "/Users/USER_NAME_HERE/FOLDER_YOU_SERVE_FROM/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Ya, I have put same WiFi.
All others function to insert or retrieve record from php on my phone is working fines, just that this method I am unable to read the response.